# Error in postfix, and while installing things?

Tags: postfix, 21.04

I recently upgraded to 21.04 from 20.04. And ever since I did whenever I download something, and install it I get this message:

```bsh
Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: ChromePanther..
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: ChromePanther..
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The programs I install usually work fine anyway, but I would like to know what happened. I have tried changing the hostname. I have also looked in postfix `main.conf` nothing seemed amiss.

The output of `grep`:

```
$ grep myhostname /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
myhostname = ChromePanther..
mydestination = $myhostname, ChromePanther, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
```

After following the advice of the answer I now get this error(Still thankful for all your help):

```
Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: ChromePanther..
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad paramete
r value: ChromePanther..
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried restarting, and I have removed the .. behind the host name. But every time I restart then use postfix I the .. comes back.

Comment: What is the output of `grep myhostname /etc/postfix/main.cf`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1356731/edit) the question with the output.

Comment: Try changing `myhostname = ChromePanther` so there are no `..` and then `sudo service postfix restart`. Not sure this will fix it, but it is the first thing I would try.

Comment: Why does it still report `misplaced delimiter: ChromePanther..` and `myhostname: bad parameter value: ChromePanther..`? Try rebooting.

Comment: Check RFC952 (Host Naming Standard) `https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc952`. Periods in hostnames have a special purpose. Your trailing "`..`" is invalid.

Comment: It goes back to .. automatically, and in the actual hostname file there is no ".."

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid entry in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file under `myhostname`, and the package configuration seems invalid too.

First stop the postfix service, then reconfigure postfix with this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Now enter a valid hostname when you're prompted for it, and you should be good to go when postfix start up again.

If postfix is not correctly installed, you might need to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` first. Alternatively, remove postfix and do a complete reinstall with the correct hostname setting.

The installation and configuration for postfix is documented in great detail in the official [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix).